# Regex to allow alpha numeric but not just numeric with minimum 6 characters and max 100

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Minimum characters required 6 and maximum characters 100.

All numeric is not allowed -111111
Alpha numeric is allowed - abc123
Special characters is allowed -_@!
Only letters is allowed- abcdefgh

```
AAAAAA =>OK
111111=> NOT OK
AAA123!=>OK
AAA12 => NOT ok minimum 6 characters 
11111_ =>OK
```

I tried with this regex ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$..it works but i cannot get the minimum 6 or max 100 in this.

^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$

All numeric is not allowed -111111
Alpha numeric is allowed - abc123
Special characters is allowed -_@!
Only letters is allowed- abcdefgh

Comment: underspecified. is `12343a` allowed? is `@12345` allowed - what about `12345@` - why regex?

Comment: `"[^0-9]"` for the regexp and `.Length >= 6` to check the length?

Comment: i could check .length but i want everything to be in a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern starts with matching `[a-zA-Z]`. If it is not required that a-zA-Z should be at the start but only at least 1 times in the whole match, if supported, you could use a positive lookahead to assert the length of 6 - 100.

Then you could make sure to match at least 1 time a-z or A-Z or a special chacter between matching 0+ times `[a-zA-Z0-9_@!-]*` on the left and on the right:

```
^(?=.{6,100}$)[a-zA-Z0-9_@!-]*[a-zA-Z_@!-][a-zA-Z0-9_@!-]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{6,100}$)` Assert what is on the right is 6 - 100 characters except a newline
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_@!-]*` Match 0+ times what is listed in the character class
- `[a-zA-Z_@!-]` Match a character a-z or A-Z or a special char without a digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_@!-]*`Match 0+ times what is listed in the character class
- `$` Assert end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZgV7mE/1)

Another option is to a positive and a negative lookahead, 1 to check for the length and the other `(?!\d+$)` to check if the match does not consists of only digits:

```
^(?=.{6,100}$)(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9_@!-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZgV7mE/2)

Comment: this doesnt allow 11111_ =>OK

Comment: @user4379225 Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/q1JLmc/2 I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a range to help with your length requirements.

`^[a-zA-Z][\w\d!_\-@]{5,99}$`

The first character being mandatory and the remaining symbols being of length 5 to 99.

As commented by Mr. Artner, you could elaborate on your need so we could provide a better answer.